# Customized non-ascii characters flagger

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I've looked around for a custom-made solution, but I couldn't find a solution for a use case that I am facing.

**Use Case**

I'm building a 'website' QA test where the script will go through a bulk of HTML documents, and identify any rogue characters. I cannot use pure non-ascii method since the HTML documents contain characters such as ">" and other minor characters. Therefore, I am building up a unicode rainbow dictionary that identifies some of the common non-ascii characters that my team and I frequently see. The following is my Python code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

unicode_rainbow_dictionary = {
    u'\u00A0':' ',
    u'\uFB01':'fi',
}

strings = ["This contains the annoying non-breaking space","This is fine!","This is not ﬁne!"]

for string in strings:
    for regex in unicode_rainbow_dictionary:
        result = re.search(regex,string)
        if result:
            print "Epic fail! There is a rogue character in '"+string+"'"
        else:
            print string
```

The issue here is that the last string in the strings array contains a non-ascii ligature character (the combined fi). When I run this script, it doesn't capture the ligature character, but it captures the non-breakable space character in the first case.

What is leading to the false positive?

Comment: Why not use `from string import ascii_characters` and say `if letter not in ascii_characters`?

Comment: @ATLUS I cannot use pure non-ascii method because the HTML documents contain characters such as ">" and other minor characters. For example, something like "Learn More >"

Comment: Why don't you implement a string of characters you don't want to include, such as the `>`? If you print `ascii_letters` you literally get `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`, so why not add your own string like `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ<>'/` etc

Comment: Could you include the contents of `unicode_rainbow_list`?

Comment: @ATLUS I don't see what difference this would make since it's easier on our end to compile the list of elements we definitely don't want versus identifying what characters were used before and are passable.

Comment: @HaraldNordgren I fixed the rainbow_list to rainbow_dictionary. But the current dictionary you see is all there is at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Unicode strings for all text as @jgfoot points out.  The easiest way to do this is to use `from __future__` to default to Unicode literals for strings.  Additionally, using `print` as a function will make the code Python 2/3 compatible:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals,print_function
import re

unicode_rainbow_dictionary = {
    '\u00A0':' ',
    '\uFB01':'fi',
}

strings = ["This contains the\xa0annoying non-breaking space","This is fine!","This is not ﬁne!"]

for string in strings:
    for regex in unicode_rainbow_dictionary:
        result = re.search(regex,string)
        if result:
            print("Epic fail! There is a rogue character in '"+string+"'")
        else:
            print(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the possibility then switch to Python 3 as soon as possible! Python 2 is not good at handling unicode whereas Python 3 does it natively.

```
for string in strings:
    for character in unicode_rainbow_dictionary:
        if character in string:
            print("Rogue character '" + character + "' in '" + string + "'")
```

I couldn't get the non-breaking space to occur in my test. I got around that by using `"This contains the annoying" + chr(160) + "non-breaking space"` after which it matched.

Comment: I'll see if I can shift to Python 3, but we've been using Python 2 due to legacy...yay legacy -.- But the solution you provided seems super simple enough

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work as expected because, in your "strings" variable, you have unicode characters in non-unicode strings.  You forgot to put the "u" in front of them to signal that they should be treated as unicode strings.  So, when you search for a unicode string inside a non-unicode string, it doesn't work as expected

If you change this to:

```
strings = [u"This contains the annoying non-breaking space",u"This is fine!",u"This is not ﬁne!"]
```

It works as expected.

Solving unicode headaches like this is a major benefit of Python 3.

Here's an alternative approach to your problem.  How about just trying to encode the string as ASCII, and catching errors if it doesn't work?:

```
def is_this_ascii(s):
    try:
        ignore = unicode(s).encode("ascii")
        return True
    except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
        return False

strings = [u"This contains the annoying non-breaking space",u"This is fine!",u"This is not ﬁne!"]

for s in strings:
    print(repr(is_this_ascii(s)))

##False
##True
##False
```